# Determining functional dependencies from a chart

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Can anyone explain to me how to go about figuring out which dependencies the following instance satisfies?

```
 A   B   C
 1   0   1
 1   1   1
```

I know it satisfies B-> A, B->C, A->C, C->A (and other implied dependencies)
but I haven't been able to grasp the concept of how to just view that from this chart. Can anyone explain how I am supposed to read it and go about determining what it satisfies with only the 0's and 1's ?

Adding another example to help better understand:

```
 A  B  C
 1  0  1
 1  1  1 
 2  2  1
```

Since there is only one row where B = 0 and B = 2, can you base the B -> A off of only one row with one unique value. Like since there is only one place where B = 0 and A = 1 does that mean it automatically holds since there is no other value of B with a 0 ?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: it was a given question on a quiz I had to take for my principles of information and database management class @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'

Comment: Is there anything like this in your textbook? And which textbook are you using?

Comment: Database Systems: The Complete Book (2nd Edition) 2nd Edition, but we don't use the book nor do I have it @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'

Comment: How about looking up the *definition* of when a functional dependency holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of answering to a question like this is to look at all the possible proper subsets of columns, let's call them X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, ... , starting first with single columns (so in this case we start with X<sub>1</sub>=A, X<sub>2</sub>=B, X<sub>3</sub>=C, and trying to see, for identical value in X<sub>i</sub>, which other columns have identical values.

For instance, starting with A, we discover that for A=1, B has two different values: this means that B *cannot* depend on A, (that is has not the same value for the value of A, which is the definition of functional dependency), while C *has* the same value (1), so that we know that this instance of relation satisfies A → C.

Looking at B, we discover that all the values are different, so we can say that all the other columns are dependent on it, and we add B → A, B → C. Finally, in analysing C, we discover that only the values of A are equal when the values of C are equal, so that C → A.

We can stop here, without considering the pairs of attributes AB, AC, and BC, since in this simple case every attribute is the determinant of some dependency, so that dependencies with set of attributes as determinant are implied by the dependencies already found.

**In summary**

In a certain instance, to know if a dependency X -> Y hold or not, we check:
if all the values of X are different, then the dependency hold; if there are rows with repeat values, then, if for each row with the same value of X the value of Y is always the same, then the dependency holds, otherwise no.

Here is another example:

```
 A  B  C
 1  2  2
 0  3  3
 1  2  4
 2  2  4
```

In this instance A → B ? Yes, since the are two rows (the first and the fourth) with the same value of A (1), and in both rows the value of B is equal (2). Is A → C ? No, since C has two different values in the first and fourth row. 
B → A ? No, since B has three rows with the same value (2) and A has different values in the same rows (1 and 2).

Comment: This would be improved if you *started* with *a definition for when a FD X -> Y holds*. Ie (quoting your summary) "for each row with the same value of X the value of Y is always the same". (You can later justify your corollary "if all the values of X are different, then the dependency holds".)